# Oracle sessions getting killed

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

We are on Oracle 10.2.0.5

We see the following messages in the Oracle alert logs

```
Thu May 08 02:44:45 AST 2014
Immediate Kill Session#: 854, Serial#: 10218
Immediate Kill Session: sess: 70000018f7a9058  OS pid: 3444858
Thu May 08 02:44:45 AST 2014
Process OS id : 3444858 alive after kill
Errors in file
```

We don't know what is it that is causing these killing of sessions. There are no accompanying ORA errors in the alert logfile when this happens.

We don't have any scripts or processes that does this. There is no user either who is killing the sessions manually.

Is there any way to know what is causing this? What process is killing the sessions etc?

Comment: Are these long-running remote sessions and they're being killed by a listener/SQL*Net timeout, or by a resource profile, maybe?

Comment: Alex - We don't have resource profiles. But yes...they are long running sessions for sure. Where do we look for listener/SQL*Net timeout values?

Comment: @AlexPoole I was checking the timeout parameters SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT(sqlnet.ora) and TIMEOUT(listener) but they seem to be controlling only the connection time and not the time after which a long running session aborts on its own. Please guide

Comment: I think I was maybe thinking about something else, those won't have that effect. Do you have EXPIRE_TIME set in `sqlnet.ora`? Wondering if the network or client is losing the connection (firewall timeout? VPN dropping?) and you're seeing Oracle cleaning up the dead connections. I have no idea if that would appear in the log as a kill, but it seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

`JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` parameter must be the culprit. It needs to be set to the default value as 1000.